# How to show online users in socket.io server in node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am creating a chess game website. I need to show online players available when a user clicks play online. From the online players list the user can click and send them req to play. Now my main problem is I'm new to socket.io and didn't find any resources regarding this online. I am not trying to show the users available in a single room rather the whole socket servers available players.
[Here Online Players will be shown in a list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGaOz.jpg)

```
function sendName(name) {
  var isNameValid = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].name === name) {
      isNameValid = false;
      console.log(name + " is already taken");
      console.log(users);
      socket.emit("nameError", "Name already exists, Try again");
      return;
    }
  }
  if (isNameValid) {
    var room = generateRoomId();
    users.push({ id: socket.id, name: name, room: room });
    socket.join(room);
    socket.emit("roomId", room);
  }
}
```

All the users are pushed in the users' array on the server-side. but I don't know how to get their name and room info on the client-side then show it in the front end.

```
<div>
            <h3 style="color:white;">Online Players</h3>
                    <ul id="users">
                    </ul>
</div>
```

Online players will be shown here.
Also when one user disconnects the online players' list should refresh which I think socket can do. I am doing a project and any help will be much appreciated and I will learn from it too.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding an example code for server and client side. The full working code is available [here](https://github.com/ucipass/stackoverflow/tree/main/socketio-example1). Each client will retrieve all the active rooms from the socket.io server after successful connections and join a room called "ChessRoom"

Server Side

```
const sockets = new Map() // holds all active sockets

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`${socket.id}: connected`);
    sockets.set(socket.id,socket) // add socket to Map object
    socket.join("ChessRoom") // join socket to demo room
    
    socket.on('disconnect', (data)=>{
        console.log(`${socket.id} disconnected`);
        sockets.delete(socket.id) // delete socket from Map object
    })

    socket.on('getrooms', (data,replyFn)=>{
        console.log(`${socket.id}: received getrooms event with ${data}`);
        const rooms = Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms).map( (room) => {
            return { name: room[0], members: Array.from(room[1])}
        })
        replyFn(rooms)
    })

});
```

Client Side

```
socket.on('connect', async ()=>{
    console.log(`${socket.id} connected`)
    const data = "OptionalData"
    socket.emit( "getrooms", data, (rooms) =>{
        rooms.forEach((room, index) => {
            console.log(`room${index}: `, room)    
        });       
    })
})    

socket.on('error', async ()=>{
    console.log(`${socket.id} error`)
})
```

Comment: I am not trying to show the users available in my room rather the whole socket servers available players in my room. I don't assign users to attribute like "socket.user=myUser" rather I keep all the users in a "users" array with their room, name, and id attribute if their name is correct. You can see it in the code I provided.  And my main problem is I don't know how to code it on the client and server-side. I know how to code for it in the front-end hbs handlebar. Thanks for the answer but could you help me with this problem?

Comment: You could technically use a separate array for user<-> socket.id mapping but I think it is easier to handle this during the login and use a new property "user" to do that.

"users available in my room" = "whole socket servers available players in my room" ?  a "room" in socket.io can only be defined in one way. Can you please clarify?

Comment: "Later you can query all sockets that are joined to your room"-users aren't joining my room. Rather i want to show all the active users in the socket server. And user can't access the socket server while login in. They are entered in the server when they click "play online" and the chess game page shows up. Also, I'm already keeping the servers active users in an array please look at the code which i provided. I'm simply asking how i can send the users array in client side and show it in online players list.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XPy2-rPLX6pLvuyq1X2K7i9LfpESro-7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I just want to send this users array "var users = [];"  to client-side and show the users name in front end.  Also if any users disconnect the online users list should update too which i think can be done once i know how to send the array to client side.